# What platform to use for YOLO output when using AMD GPU?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, opencl, yolo, amd-gpu

long time tormented by this question, I ask your advice in what direction to move. Objective - to develop universal application with yolo on windows, which can use computing power of AMD/Nvidia/Intel GPU, AMD/Intel CPU (one of the devices will be used). As far as I know, the OpenCV DNN module is leading in CPU computation; a DNN + Cuda bundle is planned for Nvidia graphics cards and a DNN + OpenCL bundle is planned for Intel GPUs. But testing AMD GPU rx580 with DNN + OpenCL, I ran into the following problem: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17656. Does this module not support AMD GPU computing at all? If so, could you please let me know what platform this is possible on and, preferably, as efficiently as possible. A possible solution might be Tencent's ncnn, but I'm not sure of the performance on the desktop. By output I mean the coordinates of detected objects and their names (in opencv dnn module I got them with cv::dnn::Net::forward()). Also, correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. Any feedback would be appreciated.

I tried the OpenCV DNN + OpenCL module and expected high performance, but this combination does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on yolov8 **ON WINDOWS** and I believe it should work with any other yolo version out there:

1- install the DirectML version of ONNX. It's crucial to choose ONNX DirectML over any other variants or versions. The Python package you need is aptly named "onnxruntime_directml".
Feel free to use:

```
pip install onnxruntime_directml
```

2- render your YOLO model into the ONNX format.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
model.export(format='onnx')
```

3- Add the 'DmlExecutionProvider' string to the providers list:
this is lines 133 to 140 in "venv\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\autobackend.py":

```
        elif onnx:  # ONNX Runtime
        LOGGER.info(f'Loading {w} for ONNX Runtime inference...')
        # check_requirements(('onnx', 'onnxruntime-gpu' if cuda else 'onnxruntime'))
        import onnxruntime
        providers = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'] if cuda else ['DmlExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']
        session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(w, providers=providers)
        output_names = [x.name for x in session.get_outputs()]
        metadata = session.get_modelmeta().custom_metadata_map  # metadata
```

✨ Comment check_requirements line 135
✨ Add the 'DmlExecutionProvider' string to the providers list

4- enjoy the 100% boot in terms of the model performance

Comment: How were you able to specify that the ONNX directml environment use the GPU? When I check the device used, my runtime shows "CPU-DML".

Comment: The regular onnx uses cpu but the dml version don't so you should make sure to configure your environment correctly. Here's a [link](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2995#issuecomment-1908556439) to my environment's pip freeze. Install the correct packages and get rid of the ones that are not on the list.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `OpenCV` doesn't support AMD for GPU optimization. If you're interested in running DL models on non-Nvidia GPUs, I suggest reading [PlaidML](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml), [YOLO-OpenCL](https://github.com/huuuuusy/YOLO-Learning-Notes/blob/master/YOLO-OpenCL.md), [DeepCL](https://github.com/hughperkins/DeepCL)